# Multiple join clause using suqbqueries with multiple where

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have 4 tables:

```
ad
image
placement
ad_placement - many to many intermediary table between ad and placement
```

the image has a FK to ad

The structure is like this:

```
ad

id | url

1   http://
2   http://
3   http:// 


placement

id | name

1    name_1
1    name_2


ad_placement
```

id |  ad_id | placement_id
     1      1      1 
     2      1      2
     3     2      2

```
image

id  | image    | ad_id 
1     http://    1
2     http://    2
3     http://    3
```

**I want to obtain the fields, url from ad and image from image, where placement=name_1**

'**' in query are only to show to what I'm referring

```
  SELECT A.id, A.url, I.image as image 
  FROM ad AS A LEFT JOIN (       
  SELECT ADP.ad_id FROM ad_placement *AS ADP*
  JOIN placement AS P ON ADP.placement_id = P.id **WHERE P.name='name_1'**) AS AP ON A.id=AP.ad_id  
  LEFT JOIN ( SELECT ad_id,image FROM image) AS I ON I.ad_id = A.id 
  WHERE A.is_active=TRUE
```

I get an error when I try to use the `where` at this line

```
JOIN ads_adplacement AS P ON ADP.adplacement_id = P.id WHE...

missing FROM-clause entry for table "adp"
```

removing 'Where' works but is not what I need

---

I added the as ADP as suggested(with italics see **) by I get the same results, like where clause is ignored

Comment: You have not defined the table alias `adp`. You probably meant to write `FROM ad_placement adp JOIN placement AS P on ...`

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name; can you post a complete answer with the simplification;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is the point of first left join?

```
SELECT A.id, A.url, I.image as image 
  FROM ad AS A 
  LEFT JOIN image AS I ON I.ad_id = A.id 
  WHERE A.is_active=TRUE
```

EDIT: Probably you mean this.

```
SELECT A.id, A.url, I.image as image 
  FROM ad AS A 
  LEFT JOIN image AS I ON I.ad_id = A.id 
  WHERE A.is_active=TRUE and
  a.id in 
  (select ad_id 
   from ad_placement adp 
   inner join placement p on p.Id = adp.placement_id 
   where p.Name='name 1');
```

Comment: I have 4 tables, with a manytomany connection between ad and placement; so my issue is on the where clause on this relation

Comment: You may have 4 or 40 tables, but for the sake of query why do you need it? Can you share table structures (in code) and what you really want. For the part you need (from your SQL) that Join was unnecessary.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I don't understand what you are saying. From his SQL "I.ad_id = A.id".

Comment: Sorry, I misread the joins. You are right. The derived table with `ad_placement` and `placement` is useless as no columns are used from there and outer join won't remove any rows.

Comment: I added the table structure

Comment: @user3541631, your added table structures seem to be useless (sorry). There is no relation directly or indirectly to images as I can see.

Comment: @user3541631, I updated my answer as much as I can understand what you need.

Answer (score 0):

Can you please share the complete query, I want to see where are you adding the where clause. However, it seems that you are adding where between two joins.
Where can be added after joining all the tables.

EDIT

```
SELECT A.id, A.url, I.image as image 
FROM ad AS A 
LEFT JOIN ad_placement AS AP ON A.id=AP.ad_id
LEFT JOIN placement AS P ON AP.placement_id = P.id
LEFT JOIN image I ON I.ad_id = A.id 
WHERE A.is_active=TRUE and P.name='name_1'
```

Comment: I think the question does contain the complete query - and apart from the missing alias it is correct

Comment: I added the table structure; I use a subquery is this affecting speed compared to using multiple queries ?

Comment: The way you have written the second join will not even help filtering the records, you can write the query as mentioned in the Answer Edit.